# Hibernate @ManyToOne annotation create table to store relation

Tags: hibernate

I have two entities // All details has been removed

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A_TABLE_NAME")
public class AEntity extends ... {
 
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BEntity b;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B_TABLE_NAME")
public class BEntity extends ... { 
...
}
```

When I start tomcat server in table creation\alter time(I use code-first conception) I have error

> ERROR: Unsuccessful: create table A_TABLE_NAME_B_TABLE_NAME (...)
>
> ERROR: ORA-00972:  identifier is too long

As I know ManyToOne relation can be stored as column in A_TABLE_NAME table. Why Hibernate trying to create table to store this relation(like this is ManyToMany relation) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ManyToOne` doesn't generate an extra table unless you specify a `@JoinTable` annotation, so I assume that the problem is somewhere on the details you ommited

Comment: I was wrong about this relation. All I need is to use @JoinTable annotation and specify table name. Thanks